# Como fazer um Gradient Map (2 cores) em uma Imagem?

Tags: java, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Estou precisando de uma solução para transformar a cor de uma imagem em preto e branco. Existem 3 formas de se fazer isso, usando grayscale que técnicamente joga o branco para o cinza, fazendo a saturação ficar -100 e através de Gradient Map (2 cores) que filtra a imagem e ajusta a cor conforme o gradiente.

Dos 3 métodos o melhor que encontrei para o que preciso foi o gradient map, pois ele deixa o branco mais branco e o escuro mais escuro, tendo um efeito fotografico melhor, além da vantagem de poder definir outras cores para criar o gradient map. Mas até o momento não encontrei nada para fazer a aplicação desse efeito no java.

Abaixo vai uma imagem referente ao que me refiro.

[image: Exemplo]

No momento eu consegui criar um algoritmo que apenas faz o Gradient Map do Branco para o Preto e ao que parece ele não esta funcionando com imagens que possuem alpha channel (a imagem fica toda preta). O objetivo em si do algoritmo é transformar a cor mais fraca da imagem na cor do `Gradient1` e escalar até a cor mais forte da imagem com a cor do `Gradient2`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class GradientMap {

    private Color RGB;

    public BufferedImage setGradientMap(BufferedImage image, Color gradient1, Color gradient2) {

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int minRGB = 255;
        int maxRGB = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                RGB = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                int media = (RGB.getRed() + RGB.getBlue() + RGB.getGreen()) / 3;
                if (media < minRGB) minRGB = media;
                if (media > maxRGB) maxRGB = media;
            }
        }

        Color[] ScaleMap = new Color[maxRGB - minRGB + 1];
        double soma = 255/(maxRGB - minRGB);

        for (int i = 0; i < ScaleMap.length; i++) {
            double color = i * soma;
            ScaleMap[i] = new Color((int) color, (int) color, (int) color);
        }

        System.out.println(minRGB + " " + maxRGB);

        Color[] GradientMap = new Color[256];

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (i < minRGB || i > maxRGB)
                GradientMap[i] = null;
            else {
                GradientMap[i] = ScaleMap[count];
                count += 1;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                RGB = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                int media = (RGB.getRed() + RGB.getBlue() + RGB.getGreen()) / 3;
                image.setRGB(x, y, GradientMap[media].getRGB());
            }
        }



        /**       #SATURATION

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                RGB = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                int media = (RGB.getRed() + RGB.getBlue() + RGB.getGreen()) / 3;
                image.setRGB(x, y, new Color(media,media,media).getRGB());
            }
        }

        **/


        return image;
    }
}
```